# Url Validating my script

Tags: php, forms, validation, url

I'm very confused as to properly validate my URL. I've tried a few options and I cant get it right. Can someone look over my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$url=filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); 
if (!$url) {
    echo The url address is not valid
}

if(strpos($url,'http://')===false)
    $url='http://'.$url;
$query="INSERT INTO `aa_aa`.`article` VALUES ('', '".$url."', '".$_POST['description']."', '".$_POST['type']."',NOW());";
$result=mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
    // echo 'Error While Inserting Article!';
    echo $query;
else
    header('Location: http://aa.aa');
```

**Edit**
Sorry Erik here it is. @Brad My friend helped me with all the scripts, so I don't quite understand the risk I'm at using this.

```
 SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
 SET time_zone = "+00:00";


 /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
 /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
 /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
 /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

 --
 -- Database: 
 --

 -- --------------------------------------------------------


 -- Table structure for table `article`
 --

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `url` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `description` text NOT NULL,
   `type` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   `title` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
   `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=137 ;

 /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
 /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
 /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection.  You **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Can you provide your table layout/create script ?

Comment: @TylinJumfit .. Not html, I want to know what your mysql table looks like... Please edit your question instead of putting additional information in comments.

Comment: Alright Erik sorry bout that.

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

```
$url=filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

This is **excellent**.  Using `filter_input()` is best practice.

```
if (!$url) {
    echo The url address is not valid
}
```

There are several things wrong with this bit:

1. Get into the habit of using `$foo === FALSE` instead of `!$foo` when you're specifically checking for the value `FALSE`, unless the value being checked is guaranteed to be boolean.  In this particular case, I don't believe there's any valid URL that could be coerced into boolean `FALSE`, so you're *probably* safe, but it's still good to get into the habit.
2. The string that you're echoing is missing quotes and a terminating semicolon, so these will produce syntax errors.
3. Nothing is preventing the script from continuing.  This means that invalid URLs are still making their way into your database.  You should either be using `exit;` after the `echo`, or restructuring your logic such that your error condition actually prevents invalid URLs from being added and the script from continuing on.

   if(strpos($url,'http://')===false)
       $url='http://'.$url;

Several things here, as well:

1. Always use curly braces `{}` around code blocks.
2. `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` will not validate URLs that don't have a scheme.  That means that this code is redundant and should be removed, since any URL which passes the `filter_input()` call is guaranteed to have a scheme (e.g. `http://`).
3. By only checking for `http://`, you're not taking into account URLs that use other schemes, like `https://`.  This isn't a big deal, though, since, as I pointed out above, this code block should be removed anyway, thanks to `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` taking care of it all for you.

   $query="INSERT INTO `aa_aa`.`article` VALUES ('', '".$url."', '".$_POST['description']."', '".$_POST['type']."',NOW());";

This is wide open to SQL injection.  Never directly embed user input into your query strings.  Whenever possible, use parameter binding and prepared statements.  Since you're using the `Mysql` extension, this isn't possible, and your best alternative is to use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

The `Mysql` extension is deprecated.  You should use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`Mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

```
if(!$result)
    // echo 'Error While Inserting Article!';
    echo $query;
else
    header('Location: http://aa.aa');
```

Again, always use curly braces `{}` around code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your error exactly but based on your table layout you need to change the sql query from

```
"INSERT INTO `aa_aa`.`article` VALUES ('', '".$url."', '".$_POST['description']."', '".$_POST['type']."',NOW());"
```

to

```
"INSERT INTO aa_aa.article 
  (url,description,type,title,time) 
VALUES 
  ('". mysql_real_escape_string($url). "', 
   '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']). "', 
   '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']). "', 
   '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']). "',
   NOW())"
```

Note that I made up `$_POST['title']` since it was missing from the original query but present in the table create script. Also you really must use `mysql_real_escape_string` to have some level of security. Ideally you would want to use PDO.

Comment: Nope didnt work, but I'm more worried about this security issue. Maybe I should pay someone to rewrite everything instead of going to my buddy.

Comment: Yes, it looks as though your friend either doesn't know the security implications of the code they have provided to you, or they want your website to be exposed.